# Native tracing functionality doesn't produce output

Tags: c#, .net, app-config, trace, system.diagnostics

I am researching how to use the `System.Diagnostics` [tracing functionality](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.trace(v=vs.110).aspx) properly, but cannot get my code to work. I have already read the official docs about [configuring tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx), [creating and initializing trace listeners](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sk36c28t(v=vs.110).aspx), the [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229547(v=vs.110).aspx) element of the app.config and some related stackoverflow posts. The msdn doc about [TraceSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource(v=vs.110).aspx) made me really confused...

My `app.config` contains the following section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="ApplicationTraceSource" switchName="ApplicationTraceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="EventLogListener"   type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener"   initializeData="PDS"     />
                <add name="TextLogListener"    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="PDS.log" />
                <add name="ConsoleLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener"    />

                <remove name="Default" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
        <source name="DatabaseActivitySource" switchName="DatabaseActivityTraceSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
            <listeners>
                <add name="QueryTextLogListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="Queries.log" />

                <remove name="Default" />
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>

    <switches>
        <!--Set value to 0 to turn of database activity log.-->
        <add name="DatabaseActivityTraceSwitch" value="1" />

        <!--Set value to 0 to turn of application log. 1 for errors. 2 for errors und warnings. 3 for more detailed error information. 4 for verbose trace information.-->
        <add name="ApplicationTraceSwitch" value="4" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

My code in my `Program.cs` is as simple as it can gets:

```
if (EventLog.SourceExists("PDS") == false)
{
    EventLog.CreateEventSource("PDS", "EventLogListener");
}

TraceSource applicationTraceSource = new TraceSource("ApplicationTraceSource");

applicationTraceSource.TraceInformation("i am information");

applicationTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, 1, "i am error event");
applicationTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Warning, 2, "i am warning event");
applicationTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 3, "i am information event");
applicationTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Verbose, 4, " am verbose event");

applicationTraceSource.TraceData(TraceEventType.Error, 5, "i am error data");
applicationTraceSource.TraceData(TraceEventType.Warning, 6, "i am warning data");
applicationTraceSource.TraceData(TraceEventType.Information, 7, "i am information data");
applicationTraceSource.TraceData(TraceEventType.Verbose, 8, " am verbose data");

applicationTraceSource.Flush();
```

The file PDS.log is being created, but it's empty.
The eventlog is empty. 
The console output is empty.

Can someone give me a hint with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I looked at the [TraceEventType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.traceeventtype.aspx) and [TraceLevel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.tracelevel(v=vs.110).aspx)  enum for setting my value of the `switch` in the `app.config`.

The **correct enum** for this attribute is the [SourceLevels](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.diagnostics.tracelevel(v=vs.110).aspx) flag.

I changed the value of my `switch`. Following solutions are now working (if I want to trace every event):

```
<add name="ApplicationTraceSwitch" value="-1" />
```

or

```
<add name="ApplicationTraceSwitch" value="ALL" />
```